# XML using SAX-writer in Progress 4Gl

Tags: xml, sax, progress-4gl

I have created a XML file using SAX-WRITER in Progress 4GL.
While opening the XML file in notepad ++, the closing tag with no data come in next line because of which the printer rejects that XML file.
I have installed XML plugins as well in notepad ++ , still no luck.
I would like the closing tag to come in same line if no data is present for the same. See below for tag 
Sample -

```
<customer>
    <name> Test Name </name>
    <addr1> Address1  </addr1>
    <addr2> 
    </addr2>
    <addr3> Address3  </addr3>
    <dob>   25/02/1990 </dob>
 </customer>
```

Comment: Please ask a specific question.

Comment: Please post 4GL code that is used to create XML file. Also mention the OpenEdge version.

Comment: Are you sure that the data which you output to addr2 isn't an embedded (and unencoded) linefeed character?

Comment: The issue was with the start element of the tag as - **h:START-ELEMENT** will start the tag and **h:END-ELEMENT** will end the tag in different line. So I have handled my data using write data to show the start and closing tag in same line **h:WRITE-DATA-ELEMENT**

Answer (score 2):

Check your data for any special characters. Perhaps clean away trailing newlines, spaces etc? It looks like your xml contains lots of heading and trailing spaces (or is it just what you have written here in the post).

For instance:

```
<dob>   25/02/1990 </dob>
```

Should most likely be:

```
<dob>25/02/1990</dob>
```

In the code below the "newline" data-element contains a newline and it translates into the same behavior as you post.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE h AS HANDLE      NO-UNDO.
CREATE SAX-WRITER h.

h:SET-OUTPUT-DESTINATION("file", "c:\temp\sax.xml").

h:FORMATTED = TRUE.

h:START-DOCUMENT().

h:START-ELEMENT("customer").

h:WRITE-DATA-ELEMENT("name","Test name").
h:WRITE-DATA-ELEMENT("addr","Address1").
h:WRITE-DATA-ELEMENT("addr2","").
h:WRITE-DATA-ELEMENT("addr3","Adress3").
h:WRITE-DATA-ELEMENT("newline","~n").
h:WRITE-DATA-ELEMENT("spaces","         ").
h:WRITE-DATA-ELEMENT("dob", "25/02/1990").
h:END-ELEMENT("customer").
h:END-DOCUMENT().

DELETE OBJECT h.
```

sax.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<customer>
  <name>Test name</name>
  <addr>Address1</addr>
  <addr2></addr2>
  <addr3>Adress3</addr3>
  <newline>
</newline>
  <spaces>         </spaces>
  <dob>25/02/1990</dob>
</customer>
```

To remove trailing and heading spaces you can use the `TRIM` function.

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for your response.
The issue was with the start element of the tag.

Comment: The issue was with the start element of the tag.
    h:START-ELEMENT will start the tag
    h:END-ELEMENT will end the tag in different line.

I have handled my data using write data to show the start and closing tag in same line
    h:WRITE-DATA-ELEMENT